# Theme resources for Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, themes, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 7/8 we had this handy [Theme Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) like `PhoneTextTitle1Style` that would reflect the users selected Theme.
What is the equivalent in Windows Store apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to find the styles that can apply to a control such as TextBlock is to select the control in the designer, go to the properties pane, click on the square next to the "Style" property, and choose the System Resource or Local Resource menus:

[image: TextBlock styles property menu]

They are also documented and demonstrated in the [Guidelines for label (or text block)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn439336.aspx)'s [XAML style gallery for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn439336.aspx#xaml_style_gallery_for_windows_store_apps)

These styles will reflect the app's current theme (dark or light) or high-contrast mode, but are not directly personalized by the user.

Windows doesn't expose the start screen background colour to apps. Windows Store apps are supposed to use their own branded colours and don't have anything analogous to Windows Phone's PhoneAccentBrush.